# elasticsearch delete documents using logstash and csv

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

Is there any way to delete documents from ElasticSearch using Logstash and a csv file?
I read the Logstash documentation and found nothing and tried a few configs but nothing happened using action "delete"

```
output {
    elasticsearch{
        action => "delete"
        host => "localhost"
        index => "index_name"
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Has anyone tried this? Is there anything special that I should add to the input and filter sections of the config? I used file plugin for input and csv plugin for filter.

Comment: Why would you want your log ingestion system to delete documents that already exist in your index?

Comment: @AlainCollins: Logstash is a generic ETL and log ingestion is only one use case out of many more that it can handle. I'd say that karina's case is a perfectly valid one.

Comment: Val is right, we are not using logstash to ingest logs but other types of objects and we need to regularly update the indexes. we get a delta csv file with deleted/updated and new objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do what you suggest, but if you're using Logstash 1.5, you need to use the `transport` protocol as there is a bug in Logstash 1.5 when doing `delete`s over the HTTP protocol (see [issue #195](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/195))

So if your `delete.csv` CSV file is formatted like this:

```
id
12345
12346
12347
```

And your `delete.conf` Logstash config looks like this:

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/path/to/your/delete.csv"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    }
}
filter {
    csv {
        columns => ["id"]
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
        action => "delete"
        host => "localhost"
        port => 9300                         <--- make sure you have this
        protocol => "transport"              <--- make sure you have this
        index => "your_index"                <--- replace this
        document_type => "your_doc_type"     <--- replace this
        document_id => "%{id}"
    }
}
```

Then when running `bin/logstash -f delete.conf` you'll be able to delete all the documents whose id is specified in your CSV file.

Comment: Thanks Val I will give it a try right now. I didn`t try to set the protocol to anything else that the default setting.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Val's answer, I would add that if you have a single input that has a mix of deleted and upserted rows, you can do both if you have a flag that identifies the ones to delete.  The `output > elasticsearch > action` parameter can be a "field reference," meaning that you can reference a per-row field.  Even better, you can change that field to a metadata field so that it can be used in a field reference without being indexed.

For example, in your `filter` section:

```
filter {
    # [deleted] is the name of your field
    if [deleted] {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "delete"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "deleted" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "index"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "deleted" ]
        }
    }   
}
```

Then, in your output section, reference the metadata field:

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "myindex"
        action => "%{[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]}"
        document_type => "mytype"
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding an extra field like "deleted" would mean a lot of changes on database logic. Every creation, reading, updating or deletion would have to take into account that there must be a filter about the value of the column "deleted". It might also impact the business logic, i.e. can a deleted user be recreated again? With the same Id?

Comment: @ostmond - Yes, you are correct.  It really depends on the business requirements.