# Want to delete documents from elasticsearch which are deleted from database

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to delete records from Elasticsearch for below use-case. What are the possible resolutions?

Fetching data from database through logstash and adding into Elasticsearch.

document_id is combination of key + some additional information.

logstash is running every few minutes to fetch latest created/modified data based timestamp.

In my scenario, we have history table for every table. So, when record has been deleted from main table, it will be added into history table with DELETE action.

I have 4-5 indexes for different purposes.

Now, I want to update/remove this related record from Elasticsearch indexes.

What are the best resolutions?

My thoughts,

1. are there any facility using logstash or any other plugin through which I can fetch those deleted records and delete from Elasticsearch?
2. is it good to implement cron job using spring-boot to deleted records from Elasticsearch?

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32900277/4604579 (hint: jdbc input to read the tables and elasticsearch output with delete action)

Comment: Thansk @Val, one more questions. Can we use different attribute of document instead of `document_id` in output section for action "delete"?